# IE 10 drag and drop still opening the file eventhough there is dragover event

Tags: internet-explorer, cakephp, file-upload, drag-and-drop, internet-explorer-10

on IE 10, everytime I drag the file to the upload filed, it still opening the file. how to prevent this? I'm confused. Please help. Is the cause due to the drag and drop is "in the file upload field" instead of creating another div tag drop area? Is there anyway to make it work on the upload field?

```
                <div id="dnd-upload-box">
                <img id="image" src="https://upload.dev/img/elements/drag_drop.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"/>
                <?php
                    echo $this->Form->input('files', array(
                        'id'        => 'file-input-0',
                        'class'     => 'file-input',
                        'type'      => 'file', 
                        'multiple'  => 'multiple',
                        'name'      => 'fileselect[]', 
                        'onChange'  => 'getFiles(this);'
                    ));     
                ?>      
                </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    // call initialization file
    $(document).ready(function() {
        Init();
    });

    // getElementById
    function $id(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }   

    // initialize
    function Init() {               
        var filed = $id("file-input-0");
        filed.addEventListener("dragenter", FileDragHover, false);
        filed.addEventListener("dragover", FileDragHover, false);
        filed.addEventListener("dragleave", FileDragHover, false);
        //filed.addEventListener("drop", FileSelectHandler, false);

    }   

    function FileSelectHandler(e) {
        // cancel event and hover styling
        console.log("selecthandler");
        FileDragHover(e);
        getFiles(e);
    }   

    // file drag hover
    function FileDragHover(e) {
        console.log("draghover");
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        e.target.className = (e.type == "dragover" ? "hover" : "");
    }   
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

The following HTML file is a complete, minimal working example for IE. (Sorry for the missing `<html>`/`<body>`/etc. boilerplate, but you don't need that for testing.)

As mentioned [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh673539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you have to prevent the default operations on the `dragover` event. Only then the `drop` event will fire, containing the file in the `event` parameter.

```
<input id="testfilefield" type="file" style="background-color: #777; width:300px; height: 100px;">
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        var el = document.getElementById('testfilefield');

        // Block the "dragover" event
        el.addEventListener('dragover', function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        }, false);

        // Handle the "drop" event
        el.addEventListener('drop', function(e) {
            var firstFile = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
            console.log(firstFile);
            alert('Drop!');
        }, false);
    }, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

In your code I don't see you handling the drop event?
As [Microsoft states in their developer manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you need to handle the drop event:

```
function dropHandler(event)
{
  event.stopPropagation(); 
  event.preventDefault();
  // Get the file(s) that are dropped.
  var filelist =  event.dataTransfer.files;
  if (!filelist) return;  // if null, exit now
  var filecount = filelist.length;  // get number of dropped files

  if (filecount > 0) 
  {
    // Do something with the files.         
  } 
}
```

Comment: This answer is not helpful unless you show how `doNothing` is implemented, because that one is the core trick to make the `drop` event work.

Comment: From the page he linked;
`function doNothing(event)
{
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
}`